# how to make an li swap variables when using sortable widget

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am currently using the [Sortable Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) to swap divs in my page but the problem is it doesn't arrange the value if the div / li when sorting it,

EX:

```
<ul class="sortable">
<li id="1">a</li>
<li id="2">b</li>
<li id="3">c</li>
<li id="4">d</li>
<li id="5">e</li>
</ul>
```

when i move 5 to the top the arrangement should arrange all of the 
id / name from

```
5 = e, 1 = a, 2 = b, 3 = c, 4 = d
```

to

```
1 = e, 2 = a, 3 = b, 4 = c, 5 = d
```

once again, how will i be able to achieve
this using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the IDs using `.prop()` method on `update` event:

```
// ...
update: function() { 
   $('.sortable li').prop('id', function(i) { return ++i; });
}
```

However, I would recommend using `data-*` attributes instead of using `id`s.